# Using calendar to determine AM or PM dates

Tags: android, class, calendar

Using the calendar class to determine AM or PM times.

```
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
            int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            int years = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int months = 1 + c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int days = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int AM_orPM = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

            try{
                if (hours < 12)
                {
                    String PM = "";
                    if (AM_orPM == 1)
                    {
                        PM = "PM";
                    }
                    timestamp.setText("Refreshed on " + months + "-"
                    + days + "-" + years + " " +  hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + PM);
                    timestamp.setTextSize(17f);
                    timestamp.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                else if (hours > 12)
                {
                    String AM = "";
                    if (AM_orPM == 0)
                    {
                        AM = "AM";
                    }
                    hours = hours - 12;
                    timestamp.setText("Refreshed on " + years + "-"
                    + months + "-" + days + " " +  hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + AM);
                    timestamp.setTextSize(17f);
                    timestamp.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){}
```

I want to set the time to AM or PM depending on the current time.
also for some reason the Calendar.MONTH value doesn't give me the correct month. It's off by one so thats why I had to add 1. Just wondering if thats normal?

```
int months = 1 + c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Comment: As a side note, there's no reason to have the if/else clause, simply say

    String AM_PM = "";
    if (AM_orPM == 1){
        AM_PM = "PM";
    } else {
        AM_PM = "AM";
    }

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is normal. Because the index of the `Calendar.MONTH` starts from 0. So that why you need `+1` to get the correct Month.

Comment: thats what I was thinking.

my main question was how do I use the calendar class to display AM or PM? Because as far as I've tested the PM works, but the AM does not.

Comment: is it my mistake, or are you comparing if hour is less than 12? (If yes, then that is AM). You're doing the other way around. And you can do a simple
 `if(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0)
  am_pm = "AM";
  else
  am_pm = "PM";`
Calendar.AM_PM returns 0 if it is AM and 1 for PM

Comment: I think it works now, but it's weird. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong besides the hours > 12; hours <12 thing...

because basically I was checking for the == 1 or 0

Answer (score 7):

Simply check `calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM`

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
if(now.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM){
   // AM
}else{
   // PM
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Determining AM vs. PM is a straightforward calculation based on hour.  Here's the code:

```
String timeString="";
int hour = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
if (hour == 0) {
    timeString =  "12AM (Midnight)";  
} else if (hour < 12) {
    timeString = hour +"AM";
} else if (hour == 12) {
    timeString = "12PM (Noon)";
} else {
    timeString = hour-12 +"PM";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40167997/250260), but it doesn´t work. I have to obtain the AM_PM value and then make the comparison:

```
int AM_PM = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
if(AM_PM == Calendar.AM){
...
...
```

It was solution:

```
   Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int AM_PM = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

    if(AM_PM == Calendar.AM){
       //AM
    }else{
       //PM
    }
```